# Orchard CMS 1.8 - Page Url not allowing .html/htm page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am using orchard CMS 1.8.

I want the page url with the extension : .html / .htm.

is it any plug-ins avaialble?

on adding .html / .htm extension with page link field showing validation message about "." extension, i do not want to remove the "." from the pattern of validation.

Is there any plug-ins / module avaialble?

How can i achieve ? is there any other possibilities.

Regards

Comment: You can enable it in web.config, but why do you need to? Why don't you just create a page in the CMS?

Comment: how can i enable in web.config file. i can not create the cms page in with .html / .htm extension as  orchard made validation for it to use .html or .htm.

Comment: Oh, you mean you want CMS dynamic pages to appear with the extension .html? Why?

Comment: i am making my old sites (Custom development) to new orchard site and old sites pages url with the extension .html / .htm and ranked with google.

Comment: OK, so that's a really bad reason to want that ;) What you want to do instead is establish permanent redirects from the old URLs to the new. You can use IIS' rewrite rules feature to do that. Search engines understand permanent redirects.